# Listings: hide some code (first encoding line)

Tags: listings, listingsutf8

In this code, I would like automatic hide the first line (in my complete example, the code is inserted from an external file).

A solution is to use firstline=2, but then it will hide the first even if this line is not a coding line.

The solution is probably with the `morecomment=[is]{}{}` command, but I don't understand how to do that.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%compilation XeLaTeX
%\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
%
%compilation LaTeX
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=Python,morecomment=[is]{\#  -*-}{-*-}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   <- this line should no appear
Python code
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Would you like hide the first line if and only if it is comment line?

Comment: Only if it is a line same as "# -*- coding: ....... -*- ", or if this is not possible, only if the line begins with # -*-  and end with -*-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version similar to yours with delimiters `# -*-` and `^^M`. The latter corresponds to the end of line character. Luckily, the end of line is eaten completely by the input processor, so that no spurious empty line remains in the output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    frame=single,
    numbers=left,
    morecomment=[is]{\#\ -*-}{\^^M}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   <- this line should no appear
Python code
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
# coding: utf-8    <- this line *should* appear
Python code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]